# Sending requests to different API endpoints every N seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use an API that has ~30 endpoints and I have settings how often I need to send request to each endpoint. For some endpoints it's seconds and for some hours. I want to implement python app that will call each API endpoint (and execute some code) after every N seconds where N can be different for each endpoint. If one call is still in progress when second one kicks in, then that one should be added to queue (or something similar) and executed after the first one finishes.

What would be the correct way to implement this using python?

I have some experience with RabbitMQ but I think that might be overkill for this problem.

Comment: What you need is a task queue (such as RabbitMQ) and a scheduler (such as Celery). If you think they are overkill there are more lightweight options. That being said, this question is really opinion-based and off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: i suggest you try python airflow for this kind of operations https://airflow.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You said *"executed after the first one finishes"*, so it's a single thread program.

Just use `def()` to create some functions and then execute them one by one.

For example

```
import time


def task1(n):
    print("Task1 start")
    time.sleep(n)
    print("Task1 end ")

def task2(n):
    print("Task2 start")
    time.sleep(n)
    print("Task2 end ")


task1(5) #After 5sec, task1 end and execute task2
task2(3) #task2 need 3sec to execute.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build your code in this way:

1. store somewhere the URL, method and parameters for each type of query. A dictionary would be nice: {"query1": {"url":"/a","method":"GET","parameters":None} , "query2": {"url":"/b", "method":"GET","parameters":"c"}} but you can do this any way you want, including a database if needed.
2. store somewhere a relationship between query type and interval. Again, you could do this with a case statement, or with a dict (maybe the same you previously used), or an interval column in a database.
3. Every N seconds, push the corresponding query entry to a queue (queue.put)
4. an HTTP client library such as requests runs continuously, removes an element from the queue, runs the HTTP request and when it gets a result it removes the following element.

Of course if your code is going to be distributed across multiple nodes for scalability or high availability, you will need a distributed queue such as RabbitMQ, Ray or similar.